# Combined code to run a 2-zone radiant floor system. Cannot get 'RadiantMain' to work. Better description in beginning of code

Tags: code-review

Trying to combine code to run a 2-zone radiant floor heating system. The menu code works perfectly. When I select MenuC 'Run main' it executes to RadiantMain prints test and then returns to menu options again. Been working on this for weeks and don't how to fix it. The RadiantMain code works ok as a stand-alone.

The second sketch starts where it says //START RUN RADIANT MAIN CODE. The menu sketch and the Radiant Main are 2 separate sketches written by 2 different developers. They do run as stand-alone sketches. I modified the menu sketch to operate my relays (MenuA and MenuB) for the manual mode it works fine. I need to be able to use the menu sketch to run 3 different functions. MenuA & MenuB to manually run the system in manual mode and a third menu item (MenuC) to run the 2nd sketch in auto mode.

I need to combine the 2 sketches together into one code

I am using a D1 ROBOT LCD KEYPAD shield. A1 through A5 are connected to temp sensors. 4 relay shield controls 2 water valves and a pump, 4th relay is unused. the menu sketch controls the 2 water valves with MenuA and MenuB. I need MenuC to run the second sketch which reads sensors sets temps and controls 2 water valves and a pump.

```cpp
//MENU CODE STARTS HERE

#include <LiquidCrystal.h>
LiquidCrystal lcd(8,9,4,5,6,7);  

int keypad_pin = A0;
int keypad_value = 0;
int keypad_value_old = 0;

int pinCount = 4;
int relay_1 = 12;//zone 1
int relay_2 = 11;//zone 2
int relay_3 = 3;//pump
//int relay_4 = 2;//open

char btn_push;

byte mainMenuPage = 1;
byte mainMenuPageOld = 1;
byte mainMenuTotal = 3;


void setup() {
  Serial.begin(9600);
  pinMode(relay_1, OUTPUT);//zone 1
  pinMode(relay_2, OUTPUT);//zone 2
  pinMode(relay_3, OUTPUT);//pump
  //pinMode(relay_4, OUTPUT);
    lcd.begin(16,2);  //Initialize a 2x16 type LCD

    MainMenuDisplay();
    delay(1000);
}
void loop()

{
    btn_push = ReadKeypad();

    MainMenuBtn();

    if(btn_push == 'S')//enter selected menu
    {
        WaitBtnRelease();
        switch (mainMenuPage)
        {
            case 1:
              Zone1();
              break;
            case 2:
              Zone2();
              break;
            case 3:
              Radiant();
              break;
            /*case 4:
              MenuD();
              */break;
        }

          MainMenuDisplay();
          WaitBtnRelease();
    }

    delay(10);

}//--------------- End of loop() loop ---------------------

void MainMenuDisplay()
{
    lcd.clear();
    lcd.setCursor(0,0);
    lcd.print("Choose function");
    lcd.setCursor(1,1);
    switch (mainMenuPage)
    {
        case 1:
          lcd.print("Run zone 1");
          break;
        case 2:
          lcd.print("Run zone 2");
          break;
        case 3:
          lcd.print("Run main");
          break;
        case 4:
          lcd.print("4. Menu D");
          break;
    }
}

void Zone1()

{  
    {
    digitalWrite(relay_1, HIGH);
    digitalWrite(relay_3, HIGH);
    lcd.clear();
    lcd.setCursor(0,0);
    lcd.print(" Running zone 1");
    lcd.setCursor(0,1);
    lcd.print(" Left to end"); 
    while(ReadKeypad()!= 'L');
    digitalWrite(relay_1, LOW);
    digitalWrite(relay_3, LOW);
    }
}
void Zone2()
{
    digitalWrite(relay_2, HIGH);
    digitalWrite(relay_3, HIGH);
    lcd.clear();
    lcd.setCursor(0,0);
    lcd.print(" Running zone 2");
    lcd.setCursor(0,1);
    lcd.print(" Left to end"); 
    while(ReadKeypad()!= 'L');
    digitalWrite(relay_2, LOW);
    digitalWrite(relay_3, LOW);
}

void Radiant()
  
    {
    RadiantMain();
    }

void MenuD()
{  
    lcd.clear();
    lcd.setCursor(0,0);
    lcd.print("Inside Menu D");

    while(ReadKeypad()!= 'L')
    {
        //Insert Task for Menu D here

    }
}

void MainMenuBtn()
{
    WaitBtnRelease();
    if(btn_push == 'U')
    {
        mainMenuPage++;
        if(mainMenuPage > mainMenuTotal)
          mainMenuPage = 1;
    }
    else if(btn_push == 'D')
    {
        mainMenuPage--;
        if(mainMenuPage == 0)
          mainMenuPage = mainMenuTotal;    
    }

    if(mainMenuPage != mainMenuPageOld) //only update display when page change
    {
        MainMenuDisplay();
        mainMenuPageOld = mainMenuPage;
    }
}

char ReadKeypad()
{
  /* Keypad button analog Value
  no button pressed 1023
  select  741
  left    503
  up      326
  down    142
  right   0
  */
  keypad_value = analogRead(keypad_pin);

  if(keypad_value < 100)
    return 'R';
  else if(keypad_value < 200)
    return 'D';
  else if(keypad_value < 400)
    return 'U';
  else if(keypad_value < 600)
    return 'L';
  else if(keypad_value < 800)
    return 'S';
  else
    return 'N';

}

void WaitBtnRelease()
{
    while( analogRead(keypad_pin) < 800){}
}
//END MENU CODE

// Title: 2 zone Radiant Heat Controller
// Date:12/01/14
// Author: Chris Biblis (My First Adruino Project )

//RADIANT MAIN CODE STRTS HERE_________________________________________________________

// #include <LiquidCrystal.h>

// LiquidC//rystal lcd(8, 9, 4, 5, 6, 7);
// define some values used by the panel and buttons
int lcd_key     = 0;
int adc_key_in  = 0;
#define btnRIGHT  0
#define btnUP     1
#define btnDOWN   2
#define btnLEFT   3
#define btnSELECT 4
#define btnNONE   5
// read the buttons
int read_LCD_buttons(){
 adc_key_in = analogRead(0);  
 // buttons when read are centered at these valies: 0, 144, 329, 504, 741
 // we add approx 50 to those values and check to see if we are close
 if (adc_key_in > 1000) return btnNONE; 
 if (adc_key_in < 50)   return btnRIGHT;  
 if (adc_key_in < 250)  return btnUP; 
 if (adc_key_in < 450)  return btnDOWN; 
 if (adc_key_in < 625)  return btnLEFT; //Changed value to 625 do to double read from select button Default is 650. 
 if (adc_key_in < 850)  return btnSELECT;  
 return btnNONE;  
}
// Setup relay shield pin array.
int relayPin[] = {2, 3, 11, 12};
//int pinCount = 4;

// Set On/Off Differentials for collector/tank temperatures.
const int diffON = 5;
const int diffOFF = 2;

// Set Default Thermostat temperature
int setTemp = 60;
int setTemp2 = 60;

//Used for calibration
int offSet[] = {-2, -1, 0, 1, 2};

//Button Variables.
int select = 0;
int up = 0;
int down= 0;
int backLight = 10;
boolean BLbutton = false;

//void RadiantMain()//RadiantMain setup
{
 lcd.begin(16, 2);              
 lcd.setCursor(0,0);
 //Introduction Screen
 lcd.print("2 zone");
 lcd.setCursor(0,1); 
 lcd.print("Radiant floor");
 delay(2000);
  
  for (int thisPin = 0; thisPin < pinCount; thisPin++)  
   { pinMode(relayPin[thisPin], OUTPUT);}

 }
// Read average voltage from sensors 
int ReadSens(int x)
{
  int i;
  int sval = 0;
    for (i = 0; i < 10; i++)
    { sval = sval + analogRead(x); }
  sval = sval / 10;
  return sval;
} 
// Calculate temperature in F from voltage of sensors.
int getTemp(int y)
{
  //Convert to Celcius
  float a = (((y / 1024.0) * 5000)/10)-273.15;
  //Convert Celcius to Fahrenheit
  float b = a * 9.0 / 5.0 + 32.0;
  return b;
}

void RadiantRun()//need RadiantRun loop
{
 // Get average Voltage 
 int z1flr = ReadSens(1);//zone  1 floor temp
 int z2flr = ReadSens(2);//zone2 floor temp
 int z1line = ReadSens(3);//zone 1 return line temp
 int z2line = ReadSens(4);//zone 2 return line temp
 int pmp = ReadSens(5);
 // Get Temperatures & Apply OffSet { -2, -1 , 0, 1, 2 }
 int zone1floortemp = (getTemp(z1flr) + offSet[0]);
 int zone2floortemp = (getTemp(z2flr) + offSet[0]);
 int zone1linetemp = (getTemp(z1line) + offSet[0]);
 int zone2linetemp = (getTemp(z2line) + offSet[0]);
 int pump = (getTemp(pmp) + offSet[0]);
  
     
  //Backlight button selection...
  if (BLbutton == true){pinMode(backLight, INPUT);} //turn backlight off
    else{pinMode(backLight,OUTPUT);} //turn backlight on
 // Display screens   
  if (select == 3){select = 0;}
  if (select == 0){
    lcd.clear(); lcd.setCursor(0,0);
    lcd.print("  Ambient Temp ");
    lcd.setCursor(6,1);
    lcd.print(zone1floortemp);
    lcd.print(" F");
}
  if (select == 1)
{
    lcd.clear(); lcd.setCursor(0,0);
    lcd.print("Set Ambient To:");
    lcd.setCursor(6,1);
    lcd.print(setTemp);
    lcd.print(" F");
}
  if (select == 2)
{
    lcd.clear(); lcd.setCursor(0,0);
    lcd.print("Z1F ");
    lcd.print(zone1floortemp);
    lcd.print("F");
  
  
    lcd.setCursor(9,0);
    lcd.print("Z2F ");
    lcd.print(zone1floortemp);
    lcd.print("F"); 
  
    lcd.setCursor(9,1);
    lcd.print("Z2L ");
    lcd.print(zone2linetemp);
    lcd.print("F");

    lcd.setCursor(0,1);
    lcd.print("Z1L ");
    lcd.print(zone1linetemp);
    lcd.print("F");

} 
 
lcd_key = read_LCD_buttons();  // read the buttons
 switch (lcd_key)
 { 
   case btnSELECT:{ BLbutton = !BLbutton; delay(100); break; }
   case btnUP:    { setTemp++; select = 1; delay(100); break; }
   case btnDOWN:  { setTemp--; select = 1; delay(100); break; }
   case btnRIGHT: { select++; delay(100); break; } 
   case btnLEFT:  { select--; delay(100); break; } 
 }

     
// only 1 zone at a time_____________NOT IMPLEMENTED YET____________

// zone 1
// if floor temp zone 1 = less then set temp then open valve zone 1 turn on pump
  // if(z1flr <= (setTemp + diffOFF))
  // {digitalWrite(relayPin[3], HIGH);} // pump on
  // {digitalWrite(relayPin[12], HIGH);} // valve 1 on
  // {digitalWrite(relayPin[11], LOW);} // valve 2 off

// if floor temp zone 1 = set temp then close valve zone 1 turn off pump
  // if(z1flr = (setTemp + diffOFF))
  // {digitalWrite(relayPin[3], LOW);} // pump off
  // {digitalWrite(relayPin[12], LOW);} // valve 1 off

// // if floor temp zone 2 = less then set temp and  zone 1  = less then set temp zone 2 valve off
//   if(z1flr <= (setTemp + diffOFF) && (z1flr < (setTemp)))
//   {digitalWrite(relayPin[11], LOW);} // valve 2 off

// zone 2
// if floor temp zone 1 = less then set temp then open valve zone 1 turn on pump
  // if(z1flr <= (setTemp + diffOFF))
  // {digitalWrite(relayPin[3], HIGH);} // pump on
  // {digitalWrite(relayPin[11], HIGH);} // valve 2 on
  // {digitalWrite(relayPin[12], LOW);} // valve 1 off

// if floor temp zone 1 = set temp then close valve zone 1 turn off pump
  // if(z1flr = (setTemp + diffOFF))
  // {digitalWrite(relayPin[3], LOW);} // pump off
  // {digitalWrite(relayPin[11], LOW);} // valve 2 off

// if floor temp zone 1 = less then set temp and  zone 2  = less then set temp zone 1 valve off
  // if(z1flr <= (setTemp + diffOFF) && (z1flr < (setTemp)))
  // {digitalWrite(relayPin[12], LOW);} // valve 1 off
    
  delay(500);  
  
}
//RADIANT MAIN CODE ENDS HERE___________________________________________________

//relay pinouts
//Digital 12 – controls RELAY 1 COM1 pin zone 1 valve
//Digital 11 – controls RELAY 2 COM2 pin zone 2 valve
//Digital 3 – controls RELAY 3 COM3 pump
//Digital 2 – controls RELAY 4 COM4 open

//sensors: 
//flr1 = floor temp zone 1 sensor
//flr2 = floor temp zone 2 sensor
//pmp = pump OFF/ON
//z1= zone 1 line temp sensor 
//z2 = zone 2 line temp sensor
```

Comment: what is the problem? ... what were you expecting to happen? ... what actually happened?

Comment: explanation at beginning of code

Comment: "When I select MenuC 'Run main' it executes to RadiantMain prints test and then returns to menu options again". If this is what you means "explanation at beginning of code", this merely described what your code does, it doesn't explain what you are expecting it to do. Your sketch works exactly as how you code it, that it, MenuC() called RadiantMain(), which doesn't do much other than setting up some pins to OUTPUT, and then back to main menu. If it not what expecting it to do, you need to be more elaborate on what it support to do...

Comment: Changed the names in the menu from MenuA to 'Zone1' and MenuB to 'Zone2' and MenuC to 'Radinat'. Zone1 and Zone2 work as expected. Using menu selection 'Radiant' to call RadiantMain which is the second sketch. 
The menu sketch will run as a stand-alone.
The RadiantMain sketch will run as a stand-alone. I need the second sketch to run complete when I select the  Radiant menu selection. 
The RadiantMain code starts after the //END MENU CODE.

Answer (score 0):

Your code for RadiantMain is:

```C++
void RadiantMain()

{
 //Serial.println("test");  

 lcd.begin(16,2);              
 lcd.setCursor(0,0);
 //Introduction Screen
 lcd.print("Solar Collection");
 lcd.setCursor(0,1); 
 lcd.print("& Radiant Heater");
 delay(2000);
 
   Serial.println("test");  
   //CODE STOPS HERE LOOPS BACK TO 'void MainMenuDisplay()'

  for (int thisPin = 0; thisPin < pinCount; thisPin++)  
   { pinMode(relayPin[thisPin], OUTPUT);}
 }
```

You say "CODE STOPS HERE" in a comment, but all it does after printing "test" is set some pins to output mode. Is that not happening? Are you expecting something else?

If you want some of the other functions (like RadiantRun) to do something then they must be called from RadiantMain or elsewhere.

---

> I need to be able to use the menu sketch to run 3 different functions. MenuA &MenuB to manually run the system in manual mode and a third menu item (MenuC) to run the 2nd sketch in auto mode.

You need to make that happen by calling the appropriate functions in "the second sketch" when the appropriate menu button is pressed.

Merely putting the code into the same file doesn't accomplish this.

Exactly what you want to happen "in auto mode" isn't clear to me. You need to be clear in your own mind what that is. For example, taking a reading, adjusting the water valves, waiting a minute, and doing it again.

Once you are clear what you want to happen in that mode, you call the appropriate functions to achieve that.

You haven't answered the questions in the comments under your main question. Without those answers no-one can help you.

Comment: The second sketch starts where it says //START RUN RADIANT MAIN CODE. The menu sketch and the Radiant Main are 2 separate sketches written by 2 different developers. They do run as stand-alone sketches.  I modified the menu sketch to operate my relays (MenuA and MenuB) for the manual mode it works fine. I need to be able to use the menu sketch to run 3 different functions. MenuA &MenuB to manually run the system in manual mode and a third menu item (MenuC) to run the 2nd sketch in auto mode.

Comment: @HaroldVermillion What do you mean with "2 separate sketches"? One Arduino can only run exactly one sketch, not more. You showed us one code. This code needs to handle everything, that the Arduino should do. Or do you try to ask how to combine 2 sketches?

Comment: I need to combine the 2 sketches together into one code

Comment: I am using a D1 ROBOT LCD KEYPAD shield. A1 through A5 are connected to temp sensors. 4 relay shield controls 2 water valves and a pump, 4th relay is unused. the menu sketch controls the 2 water valves with MenuA and MenuB. I need MenuC to run the second sketch which reads sensors sets temps and controls 2 water valves and a pump.

Comment: @HaroldVermillion See amended answer.

Comment: @HaroldVermillion why are you placing important information into a comment? ... it does not belong there ... this site is not a forum ... please place all info into your question at top of this page ... people read the question and move on when they see lack of information